# Can a base class have a member that is an instance of a derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

Can I have a base class with a member that is an instance of a derived class? How should I forward-declare or include the derived class definition? Or is there another way altogether that I should be doing this?

```
// base.h

class DerivedClass;  // Is forward declaration sufficient?

class Base {
 public:
  virtual ~Base();
  virtual void DoStuff() = 0;
  void DoSomethingWithD() {
    d_.Foo();
  }
 protected:
  DerivedClass d_;
};
```

---

```
// derived.h

#include "base.h"

class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  Derived();
  void DoStuff();
  void Foo();
 private:
  Derived(const Derived&);
  void operator=(const Derived&);
};
```

---

```
// other_derived.h

#include "base.h"

class OtherDerived : public Base {
 public:
  OtherDerived();
  void DoStuff();
 private:
  OtherDerived(const OtherDerived&);
  void operator=(const OtherDerived&);
};
```

Comment: You can likely achieve this using CRTP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern and having the instance of the derived class as a pointer in the base.

Comment: No you can't. Even with CRTP. The size of `Base` would depend on the size of `Derived`, which depends on the size of `Base`. You can, however, store a pointer or reference to the derived class.

Comment: @DyP Ah. I don't *need* a member. I could get by with a pointer. So, then forward declaration would be good enough. Thanks.

Comment: @Dyp You missed the 2nd half of my comment. My mentioning CRTP was a bit of a bumsteer ;)

Comment: @Troy Um.... oops! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you, see comments on changes:

```
#include <memory>

class Derived;

class Base {
 public:
  virtual ~Base();
  virtual void DoStuff() = 0;
  void DoSomethingWithD();      // no longer defined in-line
 protected:
  std::unique_ptr<Derived> d_;  // storing as a pointer as Derived is still incomplete
};

class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  Derived();
  void DoStuff();
  void Foo();
 private:
  Derived(const Derived&);
  void operator=(const Derived&);
};

class OtherDerived : public Base {
 public:
  OtherDerived();
  void DoStuff();
 private:
  OtherDerived(const OtherDerived&);
  void operator=(const OtherDerived&);
};

// definition moved down here where Derived is a complete type
void Base::DoSomethingWithD() { 
  d_->Foo();
}
```

Comment: "storing as a pointer as type is still incomplete" I think, strictly speaking, this isn't entirely correct. [basic.types]/5 "A class that has been declared but not defined, or an array of unknown size or of incomplete element type, is an incompletely-defined object type. Incompletely-defined object types and the void types are incomplete types." Although `Derived` isn't complete, `unique_ptr<Derived>` is, because you couldn't use it as a member otherwise: [class.mem]/9 "Non-static data members shall not have incomplete types." That said, you *do* need an out-of-line (ctor and) dtor.

Comment: `unique_ptr` is allowed to hold a pointer to an incomplete type. It only needs to be complete at the point where you call a member function on the `unique_ptr` (e.g. its destructor). Because the definition of `Derived` is visible after the definition of `Base` this isn't a problem.